# Cannot acquire data from CosmosDB through app

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am having trouble connecting to Azue Cosmos db using azure connection string, like that:

```
new CosmosClient("AccountEndpoint=https://XADDRESS:443/;AccountKey=XKEY;");
```

Executing following like gives me error in about 2-3min:

```
await cos.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("DBNAME")
```

Error message: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

I have downloaded emulator to test locally created cosmos db and everything seems to be working there without any problems.
Might it be firewall or dns problem?
I have also no problem creating my own db/container or add an item directly through Azure portal.

Comment: Please edit to provide more information. For example: which API did you set up in Cosmos DB? What other details can you provide, to help others help you?

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace and details of the exception? Not just the Message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing everything in context some simple troubleshooting tasks would include:

See if you currently have configured your DB with "All Networks" or "Selected Networks" within the "Firewall and virtual networks" section of the portal  Selected networks setting requires a firewall configuration.

[Firewall and virtual networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjV7S.png)

Review document [Configure IP firewall in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-firewall) to validate you've allowed any specific IP addresses (if you are running the app locally).